# CollectionViewCell clicked Slow pass to another View controller

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am developing iOS App. When I click on CollectionView Cell to pass the value to Another ViewController. Very Slow Pass to One ViewController to Another View Controller.

```
MEObject *objects = [_arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                UIWindow* window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
                UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
                MEDetailPageViewController *view = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailPage"];
               [view setProduct_ID:objects.me_product_id];
 window.rootViewController = view;
```

Comment: Why are using UIWindow?

Comment: Did you embed navigation controller to your intialviewcontroller?

Comment: For logout app using in appdelegate

Comment: Explain your problem then it not clear to understand.

Comment: Click on CollectionViewCell Slow pass to Other ViewController.

Comment: you want to change VC when clicked on particular cell?

Comment: yes i want change VC When i clicked on collectionviewcell Fastly

Answer (score 0):

In your `collectionview` `didselectitematindexpath` method change code as following:

```
MEObject *objects = [_arrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
MEDetailPageViewController *view = [self.Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"detailPage"];
[view setProduct_ID:objects.me_product_id];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
```